# How to give single number parameter in PyTorch?

Tags: parameters, pytorch

I want to use a single number as a parameter.

I tried to insert parameter as follows

`self.p1 = nn.Parameter()` in   `def __init__(self, ...)`
and `self.p1 = 1.0` in `def _initialize(self):`

But I am getting the error

```
    raise TypeError("cannot assign '{}' as parameter '{}' "
TypeError: cannot assign 'float' as parameter 'p1' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)
```

How can I use a single number as a parameter in my model initialized with 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument passed to [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html) should be a `torch.Tensor`:

```
>>> self.p1 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([1.0]))
```

Comment: I guess its more correct to do `torch.tensor(1.)` for a single number (what OP wants). `[1.0]` on the other hand creates a 1D array with one element.